# Vollständige Liste aller deutschen Erbwörter

Tags: vocabulary, old-high-german

Erbwörter sind deutsche Wörter, die schon von Anbeginn an Bestandteil der deutschen Sprache sind. Das sind also Wörter, die sich, natürlich oft in einer anderen Form, schon im althochdeutschen Wortschatz wiederfinden. Wörter, die später in den deutschen Wortschatz aufgenommen wurden, sind entweder Lehnwörter (Wörter aus anderen Sprachen, die auch im Wortstamm an die deutsche Sprache angepasst wurden) oder Fremdwörter (Wörter aus anderen Sprachen, die unverändert verwendet werden, zumindest was den Wortstamm betrifft).

Mir wurde erst in den letzten Tagen richtig bewusst, dass der Anteil der Lehnwörter im Deutschen deutlich höher ist als ich gedacht hatte. Viele Wörter, die ich als urdeutsch angesehen hatte, sind in Wahrheit Lehnwörter, z.B. *Fenster, Bank, Tasse, Schmetterling, Grenze, Gletscher, Jause* und viele andere.

Zu diesen Wörtern, die schon seit ca. dem achten Jahrhundert Bestandteil der deutschen Sprache sind, können jetzt ja keine neuen Wörter mehr hinzukommen. Daher sollte es eigentlich leicht möglich sein, eine vollständige Liste all dieser Erbwörter zu erstellen. Hat das schon mal jemand gemacht und diese Liste dann auch veröffentlicht?

Wenn ja: Wo kann man diese Liste finden?

Comment: Nun ja, die Definition von "Erb-" bzw. "Ur-" ist natürlich völlig willkürlich. Die Ausdrucksweise "in Wahrheit Lehnwörter" scheint mir zu suggerieren,  dass dieser Grenze (ahd.) eine besonders ausgezeichnete Entscheidung zugrundeliegt. In letzter Konsequenz (und das würde ich unter "in Wahrheit") verstehen, sind alle Wörter Lehnwörter. Zur Frage: Nimm ein althochdeutsches Wörterbuch zur Hand.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Ich hatte den Eindruck, dass Germanisten eine klare Linie zwischen Erbwörtern und Lehnwörtern ziehen. Ich will auch keineswegs Althochdeutsch lernen, sondern ich will wissen, welche modernen Wörter dem Althochdeutschen entspringen. Es werden ja auch etliche Althochdeutsche Wörter im Lauf der Jahrhunderte ausgestorben sein, so dass es im modernen Wortschatz keine Wörter mehr gibt, die auf diese ausgestorbenen zurückgehen. Angeblich sollen ja alle Erbwörter einsilbig oder zweisilbige Trochäen sein, deren zweite Silbe immer ein E enthält.

Comment: (Fortsetzung) Aber in dieses Muster fallen auch außer *Schmetterling* alle Lehnwörter, die ich in meiner Frage aufgeführt habe (*Fenster, Bank, Tasse, Grenze, Gletscher, Jause*). Außerdem sind alle genannten Beispiele Substantive, und ich würde gerne wissen, ob sich dieses Muster auch in anderen Wortarten fortsetzt. Welche heute noch verwendeten Verben und Adjektive sind Erbwörter? Wie ist die Situation bei Adverbien und Zahlwörtern? Gibt es in dieser Hinsicht einen grundlegenden Unterscheid zu jenen Wörtern, die weniger eine syntaktische sondern eher eine grammatische Funktion haben?

Comment: Ich denke solch eine Liste ist problematisch, denn man müsste näher spezifizieren, aus welcher Sprachstufe ein bestimmtes Wort ererbt wurde. Hier sind die Grenzen aber willkürlich (man wird kaum annehmen, dass genau im Jahr 750 die deutsche Sprache mit Althochdeutsch anfing und im Jahr 1050 sich Althochdeutsch komplett in Mittelhochdeutsch gewandelt hatte). Geht man nur weit genug zurück, kann man bei nahezu allen Wörtern eine Entlehnung postulieren.

Comment: Vielleicht hilft so ein Wörterbuch? Das Herkunftswörterbuch: Etymologie der deutschen Sprache. Die Geschichte der deutschen Wörter bis zur Gegenwart von Duden.

Comment: @Takkat: Nach weiteren Recherchen erkenne ich, dass du recht hast, und dass meine Frage etwas blauäugig war.

Comment: @AdInfinitum: Den Band 7 der Duden-Reihe habe ich natürlich zuhause und ich verwende ihn auch sehr häufig. Aber da dauert es meist mehrere Minuten, bis ich für nur ein einziges Wort die Herkunft herausgefunden habe. Und im Moment interessiert mich die genaue Herkunft eines einzelnen Wortes wenig. Mich interessiert im Moment eher rein quantitativ, wann wieviele Wörter zum deutschen Wortschatz hinzugekommen sind. Weiters interessiert mich, ob sich alte Wörter irgendwie grundlegend von jüngeren unterscheiden (Stichwort *Trochäen*, siehe vorige Kommentare)

Comment: Der Hinweis auf ein althochdeutsches Wörterbuch ein war eher als ein Ansatz gemeint, diese Liste zu erstellen. Geh das Wörterbuch durch und schreibe alle Worte raus, die es heute noch gibt. Ist lästig, aber ich fürchte, anders wirds nicht gehen.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Ich zitiere mal wörtlich aus meiner Frage (ganz am Ende): »*Hat das schon mal jemand gemacht und diese Liste dann auch veröffentlicht? Wenn ja: Wo kann man diese Liste finden?*«

Comment: Laut Wikitionary ist "Fenster" schon seit dem 8. Jhd Teil der deutschen Sprache, soviel dazu...

Comment: Einige Wörter sind auch nicht mal "urdeutsch" sondern "urindogermanisch" wie z.B. "Mutter" oder "Vater"

Comment: Die Frage ist nicht beantwortbar. Allein schon die Bedingung "vollständig" ist unrealistisch. Ist in etwa wie "Gibt es eine Liste aller dt. Wörter zwischen 1688 und 1733, die als 3. Buchstaben ein 'k' enthalten?" ;-)

Comment: Zumindestens für die Verben dürfte so eine Liste einigermaßen unkompliziert sein: Fast alle starken Verben stammen aus dem "Urdeutschen". Entlehnte Verben werden normalerweise schwach konjugiert.

Comment: Eine solche Liste zu erstellen, ist nicht möglich, weil die Abgrenzung "erbdeutsch" vs. "was anderes" nicht möglich ist. Opportunistisch könnte man jedoch so vorgehen: Man nehme das gesamte uns bekannte Korpus von Texten, die man einer "althochdeutschen" Sprachstufe zuordnet (nächstes Problem: Wo zieht man die Grenze?), schreibe alle Wörter heraus (Was ist ein Wort? Was zwei?) und kucke, ob sie in einer Form heute noch gebraucht werden. Bei einigen Alltagsgegenständen, die heute nicht mehr in Gebrauch sind, mag das Wort auch außer Gebrauch gekommen sein, anderes mag noch Verwendung haben.

Comment: Ein Beispiel für die Unmöglichkeit: Ist die *Glühbirne* ein Erbwort? Unsre Altvorderen haben sie bestimmt nicht gekannt, aber es ist ein zusammengesetztes Hauptwort aus zwei germanischen Wortstämmen.

Answer (score 1):

Ich kann leider noch nicht kommentieren, weshalb es nun einfach eine "Antwort" von mir gibt. Die Gebrüder Grimm haben sich sehr viel mit der deutschen Sprache auseinander gesetzt und haben damals auch das erste Wörterbuch angefangen. Dieses Wörterbuch unterscheidet sich stark zu dem uns heute bekannten Wörterbuch. Die Gebrüder Grimm haben sich ein riesiges Netzwerk aufgebaut und sind den Wörtern bis zu ihrer Herkunft nachgegangen. Hierbei haben sie versucht sämtliche Informationen miteinzubeziehen.

Vielleicht hilft dir eines ihrer Werke weiter. Über die Jahre gab es sehr viele verschiedene Auflagen ihrer Wörterbücher.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18644)

Comment: @dakab I disagree. This is a valid _attempt_ to answer the question. It might not be satisfying, but for judging the quality of an answer we have the voting system.

Comment: @Matthias: The OP asks for inherited vocabulary, particularly a compendium thereof; I don’t see how a short summary of what the Grimms did helps with that. It doesn’t even name the title of the *DWB* and lists no (bibliographical or online) references. It’s merely a vague suggestion. Not being able to comment sucks big time, but that certainly doesn’t make a comment an answer.

Comment: Since you are referring to the op: How about letting the op decide whether it's an answer for him or not? I don't see any point in discussing it here. By the way, how are you able to judge the content of the "answer"? I'm just curious, because you are writing in English.